# How to access a object residing in another javascript file through javascript file in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, console

Here I have 2 JavaScript files and I modified the `manifest.json` as below to avoid errors:

```
{
  "matches":  [
    "*://example.com"
  ],
  "all_frames": true,
  "css":[
    "css/d.css",
    "css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "js": [
    "scripts/jquery.min.js",
    "scripts/home/msg.js",
    "scripts/home/modify.js"
  ]
}
```

Now I have an object residing in the `msg.js` file and I'm only including relevant parts:

```
o = {
  "timeStamps" : t.slice(),
  "messages"   : Object.assign({}, a)
}
console.log(o);
help(o.messages, o.timeStamps.length);

function help_final(){
  return o;
}
```

Here `console.log(o)` is working fine. So i want this object `o` in another file named `modified.js`.

Here is my `modified.js` file:

```
message_object = help_final();
$.getScript( "msg.js" )
  .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log( textStatus );
    //here i need to access the object o and store it as global variable
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");
    //I need to access the obj here

    console.log(message_object);
});
```

Comment: are those 2 js files backgrond pages?

Comment: @juvian no just normal scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should export the function so you can access the object outside of that specific file to the browser so that all your files can access the object (from what it looks like your trying to store it globally anyway).

So in msg.js just do at the bottom (assuming this is only to be used in a browser)
`window.message_object = help_final;`

And then just modify your code a bit in the other files to call `message_object()` to get the `o` object.

You should also look into using javascript prototypes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Comment: `window.o` is implicit in `o=...` and isn't necessary.  I think this is an extension problem, not a javascript problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can just say `console.log(o)` in modified.js.  `$.getScript` puts the script into the world of the page, not the world of the extension.  For more information, read about the [isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment).